# Shopify how can we ensure that this product should be shown on recommendation list

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I'm working on a Shopify store and need advice on how to make sure a particular product is always displayed in the recommendation lists, regardless of user preferences. I've looked into Shopify's recommendation system and product tagging but haven't found a clear solution. Any tips on achieving this without major algorithm changes would be appreciated. Thanks!

I'm working on a Shopify store and need advice on how to make sure a particular product is always displayed in the recommendation lists. Any tips on achieving this without major algorithm changes would be appreciated. Thanks!